# Magento 2: Error filtering template: Notice: Undefined index url

Tags: magento2, php

This error is affecting the homepage after I changed the **src=""** attribute in image tag.

> "Error filtering template: Notice: Undefined index: url in
> [root]/vendor/magento/module-widget/Model/Template/Filter.php on line
> 145"

```
<?php

/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Magento\Widget\Model\Template;

/**
 * Template Filter Model
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class Filter extends \Magento\Cms\Model\Template\Filter
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Widget\Model\ResourceModel\Widget
     */
    protected $_widgetResource;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Widget\Model\Widget
     */
    protected $_widget;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Escaper $escaper
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository $assetRepo
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param \Magento\Variable\Model\VariableFactory $coreVariableFactory
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface $layout
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory $layoutFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\State $appState
     * @param \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlModel
     * @param \Pelago\Emogrifier $emogrifier
     * @param \Magento\Variable\Model\Source\Variables $configVariables
     * @param \Magento\Widget\Model\ResourceModel\Widget $widgetResource
     * @param \Magento\Widget\Model\Widget $widget
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Escaper $escaper,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository $assetRepo,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Variable\Model\VariableFactory $coreVariableFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface $layout,
        \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory $layoutFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\State $appState,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlModel,
        \Pelago\Emogrifier $emogrifier,
        \Magento\Variable\Model\Source\Variables $configVariables,
        \Magento\Widget\Model\ResourceModel\Widget $widgetResource,
        \Magento\Widget\Model\Widget $widget
    ) {
        $this->_widgetResource = $widgetResource;
        $this->_widget = $widget;
        parent::__construct(
            $string,
            $logger,
            $escaper,
            $assetRepo,
            $scopeConfig,
            $coreVariableFactory,
            $storeManager,
            $layout,
            $layoutFactory,
            $appState,
            $urlModel,
            $emogrifier,
            $configVariables
        );
    }

    /**
     * General method for generate widget
     *
     * @param string[] $construction
     * @return string
     */
    public function generateWidget($construction)
    {
        $params = $this->getParameters($construction[2]);

        // Determine what name block should have in layout
        $name = null;
        if (isset($params['name'])) {
            $name = $params['name'];
        }

        if (isset($this->_storeId) && !isset($params['store_id'])) {
            $params['store_id'] = $this->_storeId;
        }

        // validate required parameter type or id
        if (!empty($params['type'])) {
            $type = $params['type'];
        } elseif (!empty($params['id'])) {
            $preConfigured = $this->_widgetResource->loadPreconfiguredWidget($params['id']);
            $type = $preConfigured['widget_type'];
            $params = $preConfigured['parameters'];
        } else {
            return '';
        }

        // we have no other way to avoid fatal errors for type like 'cms/widget__link', '_cms/widget_link' etc.
        $xml = $this->_widget->getWidgetByClassType($type);
        if ($xml === null) {
            return '';
        }

        // define widget block and check the type is instance of Widget Interface
        $widget = $this->_layout->createBlock($type, $name, ['data' => $params]);
        if (!$widget instanceof \Magento\Widget\Block\BlockInterface) {
            return '';
        }

        return $widget->toHtml();
    }

    /**
     * Generate widget
     *
     * @param string[] $construction
     * @return string
     */
    public function widgetDirective($construction)
    {
        return $this->generateWidget($construction);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve media file URL directive
     *
     * @param string[] $construction
     * @return string
     */
    public function mediaDirective($construction)
    {
        $params = $this->getParameters(html_entity_decode($construction[2], ENT_QUOTES));
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()
            ->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . $params['url'];
    }
}
```

I tried using the *problems* tab on Vscode, if solution is found, please explain which error lead to solution.

Answer (score 0):

The `$params` array doesn't have the key `'url'`.

Comment: please elaborate

Comment: line 145 tries to read the index 'url' from the array $params. This index does not exist. I assume there is something wrong with the URL you put in "src". This is a standard PHP error and you should be able to debug it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, using Magento 2.3, as explained my cms homepage was not loading instead spat that error, after I changes to url in <img> tag. 
But the solution to my fix was none to do with the code but rather I had pasted <head></head> content in cms page, after I removed the tags, everything was  loading, strange.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue in the exception log while opening the site over the frontend.

I've debugged this issue further by adding the custom log in the shared class `Magento\Widget\Model\Template\Filter` and got the culprit media URL entry in the `exception.log` file.

```
public function mediaDirective($construction)
{
    $params = $this->getParameters(html_entity_decode($construction[2], ENT_QUOTES));
    
    $writer = new \Laminas\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/exception.log');
    $logger = new \Laminas\Log\Logger();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);
    $logger->info(json_encode($construction));
    
    return $this->_storeManager->getStore()
        ->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . $params['url'];
}
```

After adding the log, you can check the entries in the log file and track the media file entry before the error log entry. Once the URL is identified, you can remove/fix the URL to fix the error.

Make sure to remove the custom log changes from the file after the fix.

Hope this helps!!!